# Return a function from a string variable that contains another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return-value

I have a function in a string variable and I would like to perform the onclick of a button:

```
<button onclick="ReturningTrue();">Click!</button>

function ReturningTrue()
{
var stringValue = "var xyz = true; return xyz;";
return stringValue;
}
```

How can I get this onclick to work in such a way that it will return that true value? Any suggestions? Basically a function in a string that contains another function.

**Final result should be**:

```
<button onclick="var xyz = true; return xyz;">Click!</button>
```

Comment: where you want that string to be returned

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/Ly0k86bk/ ?

Comment: Nope, I want the value of xyz to be returned. Not the whole function.

Comment: but it will become `onclick=true` ,  doesnt seem to be useful

Comment: That's fine. That's just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solution:

```
<button onclick="alert(ReturningTrue());">Click!</button>
<script>
function ReturningTrue()
{
    var stringValue = "var xyz = true; return xyz;";
    return new Function(stringValue)();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<button onclick="ReturningTrue();">Click!</button>
<script>
function ReturningTrue() {
    var stringValue = "var xyz = true; return xyz;";
    return eval('(function(){' + stringValue + '})();');
}
</script>
```